# Which full text search engine is better (Thinking Sphinx or Sunspot)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx, sunspot

I choose the search engine for large project. Sunspot I liked, at least from the fact that we no need to run a cron job to reindex the data. But when I saw this http://www.vijedi.net/2010/ruby-full-text-search-performance-thinking-sphinx-vs-sunspot-solr/ I began to doubt.

Comment: I'm afraid the question will be closed soon since it's subjective.

Comment: I thought someone could give arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not the right platform for open-ended discussions. At the very least you need to post way more data about the specific instances, right now your question reads like "Which is better, bicycles or cars?" and the problem with such a question is that the only correct answer is *it depends*, it depends on your scenario, your data, etc.

Comment: Try programmers.stackexchange perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on user preference, so there's no straightforward answer. Maybe you could go through pros and cons of each one and decide for yourself?